# Proving the canonical form of a vector field near a regular point on the boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to solve Theorem 9.35 of Lee's *Introduction to smooth manifolds*:

*Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary and let $V$ be a smooth vector field on $M$
that is tangent to $\partial M$. If $p \in \partial M$ is a regular point of $V$, there exist smooth boundary coordinates $(s^i)$ on some neighborhood of $p$ in which $V$ has the coordinate representation $\partial / \partial s^1$.*

The author suggests to use the double of the manifold $D(M)$. I assume that we have to use the same theorem for manifold without boundaries at some point.

Here's my (vague) attempt:

- I take a boundary chart $(U,(x^i))$ around $p$. We have $x \in \partial M \iff x^n = 0$.
- I think I use this chart to make a usual chart $(\tilde{U},\tilde{\psi})$ on $D(M)$ around $p$ by mirroring the map and using the gluing lemma.
- The vector field $V$ can also be smoothly extended to $\tilde{V}$ on $D(M)$
- Since $V_p$ is not zero, there exists a non-zero coordinate $V_p^j$. Since $V_p$ is tangent to $\partial M$, it means that $j \neq  n$. Since $V$ is smooth, this is also true on a neighborhood of $p$. Let's consider the submanifold $S$ defined by $S = \{ x \in \tilde{U}, x^j = 0 \}$. $V$ is not tangent to $S$.
- I apply the original theorem for smooth manifold without boundary. Thus, we have coordinates $(\tilde{s}^{i})$ such that $V = \partial / \partial s^1$ on $D(M)$

Now, I'm stuck. I don't know how to get back to $M$ and get boundary coordinates $(s^i)$ from $(\tilde{s}^i)$.